# Exported JSON coming out in the wrong format

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to export a table in JSON format from Google Cloud Storage using a Python script. When I manually export the table as a JSON from BigQuery it is done in this format.

```
{"f0_":5586.2928892104655}
```

However when I download it using my Python script I receive it in this format.

```
f0_
5586.2928892104655
```

This is the code I have been using to export and download the JSON.

```
def export_data_to_gcs(data, test2, destination):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(data)
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset('FirebaseArchive')
    table = dataset.table('SumConnectionTime')
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

    job = bigquery_client.extract_table_to_storage(
        job_name, table, 'gs://firebase_results/SumConnectionTime.json')
    job.source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'

    job.begin()

    wait_for_job(job)



def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
            return
        time.sleep(1)

export_data_to_gcs(data, 'SumConnectionTime', destination)

client = storage.Client(project=data)
bucket = client.get_bucket('firebase_results')
blob = bucket.blob('SumConnectionTime.json')
with open('SumConnectionTime.json', 'w') as file_obj:
    blob.download_to_file(file_obj)
```

I need it to be the format that I initially received because I am running a json.load with the values given back. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems we need to take a look at the `download_to_file` method of your `blob` object since that's where the file is written. Also, the  `blob` method used to read the `bucket`.

Comment: would there be another way to download the file without using a `blob` method?

Comment: How could I tell if I don't know what that method is doing? It seems to be a custom method, nothing from the standard library.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase that, Is there another method, similar to blob, that downloads files in the same fashion?

Comment: Again, how would I know what is similar to `blob` if you don't tell us what `blob` is? You need to give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that you are not specifying the destination format that you want BigQuery to export into. If you want JSON, try replacing your line about the source_format with this:

```
job.destination_format = NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
```